# symfony2: how to use translator in console command

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use translator in symfony2 (2.3.0) console command, but I can't make it work.
Here is what I've done so far:

```
use Symfony\Component\Translation\IdentityTranslator;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class SendMessageCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure() {
        $this->setName('mycommand:sendmessage')->setDescription('send message.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $translator = $this->getContainer()->get('translator');

        echo $translator->trans('my.translation.key'); // not working
    }
}
```

`my.translation.key` is exists in messages.yml. Any idea how to make it work?

thanks!

Comment: @Touki it just output the translation key. no errors.

Comment: Try adding in your config.yml `framework.translator: { fallback: "%locale%" }` and `framework.default_locale: "%locale%"` then clear the cache

Comment: @Touki thanks, but I already have both entries in config.yml. Clear the cache doesn't make any difference. I see that in app/cache/dev/translations directory the catalogue for the default locale is not generated when running only this console command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found that in symfony2 console command, the default locale defined in `config.yml` is never used so the locale is `NULL`. So the translator will never use any translations locale available. That's why the translation key is returned intact instead of the translation.

I got this hint when I run only the console command which is trying to translate something, but the catalogue in app/cache/dev/translations folder is not generated.

So, this is how I do to make translations in console command works (in my case, I set it to id_ID):

```
$translator = $this->getContainer()->get('translator');
$translator->setLocale("id_ID");

echo $translator->trans('my.translation.key'); // works fine! :)
```

Hope that could help anyone facing the same problem. :)